# C# code for auto decrypting an encrypted exe file when user double click it

Tags: c#, winforms, security, encryption

I want c# code that will take an exe file, encrypt the exe file and then embed decrypt function in tht exe file..what i want is to know if theres a technique when user double click the encrypted exe file it auto decrypt it self and runs the application.. please help i have not found any solution. I have successfully encrypted my exe with des but now the exe will not run because of the encryption..

Comment: You need an extra portion of the executable that isn't encrypted, that will decrypt the rest, but what or who exactly are you protecting the contents from?

Comment: What's the point of encrypting a file and embedding decryption key next to it?

Comment: Since the decryption implementation and the decryption key have to be stored relatively in the open the whole act seems rather futile, any hacker worth his or her salt would be able to get to your encrypted content.

Comment: "I have successfully encrypted my exe with des" - then that strongly suggests you're not making the right decisions in 2018. DES should only be used to interoperate with *old* legacy systems that cannot be updated.

Comment: NTFS already has a perfectly good file encryption system where the _secret is `not` in the file itself_

Comment: Sounds like you search for a C# obfuscator. There are several tools out there, that do this job. But be aware that you could run into problems if you use reflection in your code (or any 3rd party assembly).

Comment: #Damien_The_Unbeliever please do suggest good modern encrypters i am in learning phase thats why i asked the question.

Comment: Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen what should i do then? I want a system which encrypts an exe file and that file get decrypted when opened and executed. Can you point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Encryption isn't a magic wand. It doesn't transform something from insecure to secure. We'd need to understand your use cases and *threat model*. But this sounds like the typical "I want my code to run on <somebody else's machine> but I don't want them to be able to access/decompile that code". Realise that that's mostly a lost cause (see - Movies, Video Games and DRM). The only way to keep your code safe is to *keep it on machines that you control*.